# PHP HTML, apply class to html button and not to PHP linked text

Tags: php, html, class, button

I have this code i use for my website to display text and a button:

```
<?php if ($slide1 != null ) : ?><li><img src="<?php echo $this->baseurl ?>/<?
php echo htmlspecialchars($slide1); ?>" /><p class="caption">
<a href="/algemene-informatie"><?php echo ($slidedesc1); ?>Meer info</a></p></li>
```

Right now the entire thing is displayed as a button with the class "caption". I only want class "caption" to be aplied on "Meer info" and not to "$slidedesc1". How would I do that? Do I change the position of class?

**Caption properties:**

```
.callbacks .caption {
color: #fff;
display: block;
font-size: 45px;
max-width: none;
position: absolute;
text-align: center;
text-shadow: 0 0 1px #555;
top: 20%;
width: 100%;
z-index: 2;
}

.callbacks .caption a {
background-color: #3498DB;
border-bottom: 5px solid #2980B9;
position: relative;
padding: 10px 40px;
margin: 0px 10px 10px 0px;
border-radius: 10px;
font-family: 'Pacifico', cursive;
font-size: 25px;
color: #FFF !important;
text-decoration: none;  
z-index:11;
}

.callbacks .caption a:hover
{background: #555;  border-bottom: 5px solid #000; text-decoration:none;}


.callbacks .caption a:active
{
transform: translate(0px,5px);
-webkit-transform: translate(0px,5px);
border-bottom: 5px solid #333;
transition: all 0.1s;
-webkit-transition: all 0.1s;
background-color: #444;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this code :

```
<?php if ($slide1 != null ) : ?><li><img src="<?php echo $this->baseurl ?>/<?
php echo htmlspecialchars($slide1); ?>" /><p>
<a href="/algemene-informatie"><?php echo ($slidedesc1); ?><span class="caption">Meer info</span></a></p></li>
```

Comment: what are caption's properties  ?

Comment: just a normal css styled button, I added the class "caption" properties beneath my question.

Answer (score 0):

Does this work?

```
<?php
if ($slide1 != null ) {
echo "
<li>
<img src='".$this->baseurl."'".htmlspecialchars($slide1) ."/>
<p>
<a href='/algemene-informatie'>
$slidedesc1
<label class='caption'>
Meer info
</label>
</a>
</p>
</li>
"
?>
```